# Slow results when querying every n'th row

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the method below, I'm able to return every n'th row, which is sometimes optimal when I'm querying records over a longer-than-normal time period.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, [column name] 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, [table name] 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % [n] = 1
```

While this works, it slows the query down tremendously.  For example, querying every row over a 24 hour window might take 0.1 seconds.  However, querying with every n'th row, the result takes 12-13 seconds.  I'd love to be able to expedite this, but don't know what could be done.

Comment: Presumably your mysql version < 8? If not then user *window function*

Comment: @Stu Technically MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Window functions are supported in MariaDB from 10.2, so use them!

Comment: @Stu Thanks!  I have never used them, so I will look into it.  Much appreciated.